# Dynamic .NET WebAPI 5.2 Controllers based on some an abstract base type

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, reflection.emit

Assuming that the REST and Data access interactions will be somewhat standard, I want to be able to create an abstract type to represent entity objects to pass back and forth from REST client (e.g. JavaScript in a browser) to the persistence layer without writing/registering/routing a bunch of different WebAPI controllers.

How can one create one controller base type implementation to manage persistence of several different entity type REST interactions?  I.e. how can I make this work with WebAPI?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace DynamicEntityApiControllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class EntityController<T> : ApiController
        where T : EntityObject
    {
        private readonly IDaoProvider daoProvider;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EntityController{T}"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="daoProvider">The DAO provider.</param>
        protected EntityController(IDaoProvider daoProvider)
        {
            this.daoProvider = daoProvider;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the name of the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>
        /// The name of the collection.
        /// </value>
        protected string CollectionName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)this.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the specified entity by key from the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Get(string key)
        {            
            return this.daoProvider.Output<T>(this.CollectionName, key).Data;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates or updates the specified entity by key in the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        /// <param name="updating">The updating.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Put(string key, [FromBody] T updating)
        {
            var daoObject = DaoEntity.Create(this.CollectionName, key, updating);
            return this.daoProvider.Input<T>(daoObject).Data;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates or Updates the collection specified entirely.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="replacingCollection">The replacing collection.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEnumerable<T> Put([FromBody] IEnumerable<T> replacingCollection)
        {
            return this.daoProvider.Input<T>(replacingCollection
                            .Select(o => DaoEntity.Create(this.CollectionName, o)));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// creates a new entity in the specified collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="creating">The creating.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public T Post([FromBody] T creating)
        {
            var daoEntity = DaoEntity.Create(this.CollectionName, creating);
            return this.daoProvider.Input(daoEntity).Data;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deletes the specified entity by key from the collection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
        public void Delete(string key)
        {
            this.daoProvider.Delete(this.CollectionName, key);
        }
    }
}
```

the JavaScript client must look/act something like this:

```
$.ajax({url: '/Book', method: 'POST', data: {title: 'This StackOverflow Post', pageCount: '124' })
    .done(function(data) {
      $.get('/Book/'+data.Key).done(function(data) { 
        // this will return the book you just created
        console.dir(data);
      })
    })

    $.ajax({url: '/Book', method: 'POST', data: {title: 'Some other StackOverflow Post', pageCount: '236' })
    .done(function(data) {
      $.get('/Magazine/'+data.Key).done(function(data) { 
        // this will return 404 status code because you're asking for the book's key 
        // in the Magazines collection
        console.dir(data);
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

the sample solution has a bunch TODO here (like actually do right with ETag header, if-match, etc...) but I had to do about 4 queries across StackOverflow to find these bits.

Prerequisites:

- Autofac (IoC) integration with WebAPI
- WebAPI Controller Location / DependencyResolver (these are not the same things)
- C# Generics
- Reflection IL Emitting
- very minimal REST understanding and what an ETag is.

[GIT source folder](https://github.com/scottleyg/ScottleySampleProjects/tree/master/DynamicEntityApiControllers)

briefly, here is the logic:

- create a base type (entityobject)
- identify all those entities at IoC Registration time via reflection (Implementer is responsible for specifying which assemblies to scan)
- create concrete implementations of abstract class EntityController via IL Emitting

  - Tell the SupportsDynamicControllerTypeResolver about these dynamic types
- IDaoProvider implementation is the "persistence" layer.  implement your persistence logic here.. in this sample, an in memory dictionary is used.

And what happens when a request is made:
 - RouteTable is interrogated (finds {controller}/{key} route which is an HttpRoute
 - Controller name matches EntityObject implementer name minus Entity.  I.e. BookEntity => BookController
 - SupportsDynamicControllerTypeResolver is required here to get dynamic assembly types as valid candidates for WebApi to try to activate.
 - HTTP Put/Get/Post/Delete methods find the correct method
 - persistence layer does the rest